# How to send self signed certificates in every request using RestTemplate?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I want to call a REST service with my spring application. To access that service i have a client certificate (self signed and in X.509 format) for authorization. What is the proper way to authenticate against the rest service?

I have two certificate file and one private key that I want send to service in each request

```
private final String CLIENT_CERT = "C:\\Cert\\cert.cert";

private final String CLIENT_KEY = "C:\\Cert\\client.cert";

private final String LYNX_ROOT_CERT = "C:\\Cert\\root.crt";
```

This is my request:

```
private ResponseEntity<String> restTemplateGetForObject(UriComponentsBuilder builder,
        Map<String, String> uriParams) {
    HttpEntity<?> entity = getEntityWithHeaders(HttpMethod.POST);
    ResponseEntity<String> resp = restTemplate.exchange(builder.buildAndExpand(uriParams).toUri(), HttpMethod.POST,
            entity, String.class);

    return resp;
}
public ResponseEntity<String> updateOrCreateAlarm() {
    String BaseUrl = configuration.getUrl();
    String port = configuration.getPort();

    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(BaseUrl + ":" + port + "/api/v1/alarm");
    Map<String, String> uriParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    uriParams.put("alarm_group", "LYNXKEYPRO");
    uriParams.put("alarm_channel", "001");
    uriParams.put("alarm_state", "ALARM");
    uriParams.put("ip_address", "10.6.1.42");
    uriParams.put("computer_name", "WS-B2-Lab1");
    uriParams.put("version", "2");
    uriParams.put("additional_text", "Custom Text to display with alarm");
    return restTemplateGetForObject(builder, uriParams);

}
```

Comment: I am not fluent with Spring, but with standard JEE, you simply have to set a keystore containing the certificate and private key on the request builder.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would create a truststore and add this certificate as an entry there.

2) When start your rest *client*, make sure the truststore is included in the jvm process.

Here are the details:

Self-signed certificate (For Windows). **Note, in your case you probably already have the certificate. Just make sure it is added into the truststore. Also in the dev environment, keystore and truststore can be the same**. You can google how to do it. I used *keystore Explorer*.

```
cd  certificate directory
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\keytool.exe"  -genkey -alias signFiles -keystore badsslkeystore
```

badsslkeystore – keystore name
assword – changeit.
-alias – keystore entry, in our case it is signFiles.

http://java-buddy.blogspot.cz/2016/07/java-example-of-ssl-server-and-client.html

For client:

```
$ java -jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password "...JavaSSLClient.jar"
```

Or set them as System properties.

```
public static void setClientSslConfig() {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", TRUSTSTORE);//TRUSTSTORE - truststore location in the file system.
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);
```

}